# Iterators in C++ begin/end vs a:collection

Tags: c++, iterator

Can someone enlighten me on the difference between

`for( auto a : world )`

and

`for( auto a=world.begin() ; a != world.end(); a++ )`

does the former make a (deep) copy of the vector/array [world] ? If `a` is changed inside the loop, the changes seem to be lost in the former and preserved in the latter.

TIA
Richard

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the first loop doesn't make a deep copy of `world` as a whole, *but* at each iteration, an item from `world` is copied into `a`.

If you want to make changes to `a` and have them affect the original collection, you normally want to declare `a` as a reference:

```
std::vector<int> world;

// add 2 to each item in `world`:
for( auto &a : world )
    a += 2;
```

In this case, `a` is a reference to the item in `world`, so adding to it modifies the item in `world`.

Answer (score 4):

```
for( auto a : world ) { ...something... }
```

is roughly equivalent to

```
for( auto it = world.begin(); it != world.end(); ++it ) {
    auto a = *it;
    { ...something... } }
```

so `a` here is a copy of the value from the iterator, and changes to it won't affect the collection it was copied from.

Comment: Appreciate the quick answer, it helps too